# The Server is Busy Now. Try again Later

Tags: sharepoint-server, error

Sometimes I have some new alert or event in my portal, and when alot of users hit or Refersh the page on the same time I get some issue and my portal stops.

The last Error I got is:

> The Server is Busy now. Try again later

sometimes I get this Error:

> -You have exceeded your profile storage space

I am using SharePoint 2013 with Windows Server 2012.

Is there any setting I have to do to prevent this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is your hardware related problem, You are running into the capacity issue. easy fix is increase the memory(ram) on the WFE to get the better result.

You can monitor your WFE while all users hit the sites, check how CPU behave, how Memory behave, Hows the DB server respond.

check this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4215da16-8e53-43d7-b4d5-1226f5119ef2/the-server-is-busy-nowtry-again-later-error-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: thank you for your answer, But what you mean by WFE.

Comment: WFE means web front end servers.